# How can I create plots with different y variables in a loop in R?

Tags: r, plot

Apologies in advance, I'm quite new to R and programming in general.

I have a dataset of several water quality variables that were all measured annually. What I want to do seems simple enough, which is to create several exploratory scatter plots that plot each variable against time on the x-axis. I've been looking into doing this with a loop (yes I know that loops aren't favored, but as I said, I'm new) to automate it, as I will have to do a bunch of analyses following this and don't want to write a bunch of redundant code.

Producing each graph has gone fine, but I'm drawing a blank at how I can give each graph a unique identifier (i.e., write the y label and chart title based on the particular variable I am looping).

Here is what I have for code, though I'm not sure how useful it may be. Advice for how to coax the loop function into doing what I want it to would be great.

```
WQdata <- data # the dataframe
names <- colnames(WQdata[, -1]) # names of variables, excluding Year which was first column
Year <- WQdata$Year
vars <- c(WQdata[, -1]) # removed year, 

for (i in vars) {
    xlim <- range(Year) 
    ylim <- range(i)
    plot(x=Year, 
         y=i,
         type="p",
         main=paste(names[i]),
         xlab="Year",
         ylab=paste(names[i]))
}
```

What this has done so far is produce each plot as I wanted it to, but without those customized labels.

Again, I apologize for being vague or leaving things out - feeling confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Try dynamically creating a title using the variable name and just regular old string formatting. For axes, you'll need to create a lookup table (similar to a dictionary in Python) to map the appropriate axes to a given graph.

Comment: Thanks. Given that this is meant to be an exploratory procedure I won't dwell on getting it perfect, so if I can have dynamic titles then I won't bother with the axes.

I think what I'm having trouble with is ensuring that each plot is titled according to the column of data that it is plotting, but right now it inserts much more text than I want in the title, suggesting my reference ("names[i]") is not working how I thought it should...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ggplot with facets for less code without loopings and repeating code...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>%
    gather(-mpg, key="var", value = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = mpg, y = value)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Still not fully resolved about loops but this will allow me to move on.

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a list of titles and y labels, and refer to them inside the loop.

An example using `mtcars`:

```
labels <- list("cyl" = c("main - cylinders", "ylabel - cylinders"),
               "disp" = c("main displacement", "ylabel - cylinders"),
               "hp" = c("main horsepower", "ylabel - horsepower")
               )


for (i in colnames(mtcars)[2:4]){
  plot(x=mtcars[,'mpg'], 
       y=mtcars[ ,i],
       type = "p",
       main = labels[[i]][1],
       xlab= "mpg",
       ylab= labels[[i]][2]
  )
  }
```

Comment: Nice! But using list of lists seems overkill - a list of character vectors is probably sufficient.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the suggestion! I improved the answer, but should I keep the same subscripting: `labels[[i]][[2]]`? I don't see a better way to do this, but it doesn't look very nice.

Comment: You can now get rid of the double brackets on the second subset. That is, `[[i]][[2]]` can be `[[i]][2]`. And since you're using a named list it might be nicer to say `for (y in c("cyl", "disp", "hp"))` (make sure the list names match `disp` not `displacment`). Then you could do `y = mtcars[, y]` instead of relying on indexing and column order. And of course replace the other `i`s with `y`s.

Comment: @Gregor Nice! Thanks again. I kept the `i` because changing to `y` could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using character vectors and indexing:

```
df <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2013,2014,2015,2014,2013), 
                 INCHES = c(12,36,34,23,12), 
                 TEMP = c(89,98,76,87,65),
                 PRESSURE = c(0.05, 0.10, 0.12, 0.85, 0.90))

# Must correspond to variables except for `YEAR` in `df`
# `y_axis_labels` are your custom labels
y_axis_labels = c("Inches", "Temperature", "Pressure")
y_axis_vars = names(df[, -1])

xlim <- range(df$YEAR)

for(i in 1:length(y_axis_vars)){
  curr_y_axis_var = y_axis_vars[i]
  ylim <- range(df[[curr_y_axis_var]])

  plot(x = df$YEAR,
       y = df[[curr_y_axis_var]],

       type = "p",
       main = paste(curr_y_axis_var),
       xlab = 'YEAR',
       ylab = paste(curr_y_axis_var))
}
```